# Pass json data from Google Maps to MVC controller with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I want to store data about addresses and coordinates of markers on map, so I'm creating button in Infowindow which will redirect me to form on another view (also with another controller). I want this form to be already filled with data about coordinates and address. I have function called on button click with AJAX code in it to send JSON data to method in controller. Problem is that after clicking on button controller method isn't called (although function call works properly while debugging). I've been searching a lot for a solution, but I really don't know what did I do wrong.

Call to `addMarker`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
            if(infowindow) infowindow.close();
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: data});
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

            var buttonAdd = document.getElementById('addButton');

            buttonAdd.onclick = function() {
                addMarker(event.latLng, address);
            }
        });
```

JS function with AJAX:

```
   function addMarker(location, fulladdress) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(fulladdress + location) //it's ok, i checked with firebug

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Incidents/Create",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: data
        })
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class IncidentsController : Controller
    {
        //some code
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string JsonStr)
         {
             return View();
         }
         //some code
    }
```

For now I'm just trying to get to another view without doing anything with recieved data, but it's not working. There's definetely something wrong with ajax or controller. I'm new to MVC, JS and AJAX, so please forgive me if it's something stupid. Thanks in advance.

TL;DR - Clicking on button should result in recieving another view with partially filled (with address and coordinates) form.

Comment: For starters show enough code context so we can see how you use `addMarker()`. A better explanation of expected results would help also

Comment: I've updated question, hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: Not a good thing binding one event listener inside another. Just call your `addMarker()` inside the first listener otherwise nothing will happen until the button is clicked

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saying that nothing will happen. Till some point it's working as expected - after I click on marker I get Infowindow with button. After I click it it's calling `addMarker` which is filling `data` with `JSON.stringify` value. And that's it - ajax calling controller method, passing data, returning view, this is what I need to fix.

Comment: well your statement said *"nothing happens"* . Really not clear what your issue is then. One thing that is missing is a handler in your ajax for the response. Not sure what you intend to do with it from there

Comment: What I meant is that controller method isn't called by ajax in `addMarker`, this function itself is. I have to get a response? I just wanted to pass some data to another view through controller. I want address and coordinates from JS in Home/Index to fill form in Incidents/Create.

Comment: Use browser dev tools network to see if ajax call is being made. Sounds like a design flaw though if you are intending to redirect to another view

Comment: Why it's a flaw? I could make this form in the same view, but for now I think it's better if it is in another view. Ajax call is being made, but it's giving 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: unless you persist the data somehow in session at server it won;t be available in another view

Comment: Well, that's not what I wanted to hear, but at least now I know that it's dead end. Thanks for help. But if I may ask, if I can call method from another controller (parameter `controllerName` in url), why can't I return view from this controller?

Comment: need to realize how server side scripts work. Once they have generated the output they are done with that data and it is cleared from server memory. If you load another page...server doesn't know you just sent some data to it via ajax

Comment: I forgot to mention that in another controller's method I wanted to save recieved data in model and pass that model to this new view (by `return View(object)`, isn't this possible?

Comment: Yes its possible, you can just specify the View Name that you want to render and pass in the model. e.g. `return View("ViewName", model)`

Comment: Ajax call is alright now, method is called (I set breakpoint and it was hit), but I'm not getting specified view, any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

You are using `dataType: "json"`. If you want to post `JSON` in MVC then you need to create appropriate model with the same format that you are going to post.

Take a look at below example.

Controller :

```
 public class JsonPostExampleController : Controller
 {
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult JsonPost(JsonModel data)
     {
          return View();
     }
 }
```

Javascript :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "JsonPostExample/JsonPost",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'name': 'ravi' },
    success: function (data) { }
});
```

Model :

```
public class JsonModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Now as per your requirement, we can not use `dataType: "json"` as you can't create model according to google's response format for fulladdress and location.

So you need to use `dataType: "text"` and for that you only need to modify your javascript.

Update your javascript block with below :

```
function addMarker(location, fulladdress) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(fulladdress) + JSON.stringify(location)

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Incidents/Create",
        dataType: "text",
        data: { JsonStr : data }
    });
}
```

and your controller code remains same as :

```
public class IncidentsController : Controller
{
    //some code
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string JsonStr)
    {
        return View();
    }
    //some code
}
```

now you should be able to get your data in string format at server side. If you want `JSON` server side then you can parse the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's almost working. ;p According to Firebug ajax call is ok, I can see my data string, but I'm not getting another view from method in controller. I tried `return View()` and `return View("Create")`, nothing happens. Any idea why? As a reminder, this view is handled by other controller than view that I'm sending data from.

Comment: If you want to use view that is handled by another controller then you need to pass the absolute path of that view, for an example `return View("~/Views/XYZController/Create")` or `return View("../XYZController/Create")`

Comment: I'm not sure if we're on the same page. I'm sending data from Home/Index (nothing handled in HomeController) to /Incidents/Create (with Ajax I'm calling method in IncidentsController). So views are in different controllers, but the method I'm calling is in controller of the view that I want to return.

Comment: Okey, if i'm not wrong then your javascript code for making ajax call is in Index View of HomeController and you are calling Create action of IncidentController. If so then it should work fine, because you can post on any url from any url of same domain using `$.ajax`. If domain changes then `jsonp` comes in picture.

Comment: If you are still facing problems then please update question and add code you are writing.

Comment: Yes, that's excatly what I'm doing. The call itself is working, but I'm not redirected to Create View, which I think should happen cause of `return View()` in `CreateIncident` method in IncidentController. I tried many ways and the only one that is working is redirecting in Ajax call after success, but then I don't have any data in form in Create View, even if I pass it in model's object like `return View(object)`.

Comment: Well actualy as formally your question resolved problem with passing json I created new question with new code and explanation of a problem that I'm occuring some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640387/mvc-controllers-method-not-returning-view

Comment: Then your will have to redirect it in the success event of ajax call

Comment: Probably, but then I could access sent data only if meanwhile I would save it to DB, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I have posted answer, most probably it should work for you. Tell me if you are still facing problem :)